# How to update a table from 2 others that contain the old values and the new values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables, 2 of them are temporary tables. One has old values to be updated and the other has the new values.

The first table contains the columns `Telephone` and `ID`, and the other two only contain one column, `telephones`

Example

Table `TelephonesOrganization` :

```
ID        Telephone 
1          1234
1          4567
1          5678
```

Table `TelephonesToUpdate`:

```
Telephone
1234
4567
```

Table `TelephonesNewValues`:

```
9999
9999
```

The values to update in `TelephonesToUpdate` correspond directly to the same row in `TelephonesNewValues`, for example 1234 will take the value 9999, the ID is also a variable In this case Its 1.

I have tried using and `UPDATE` and in the Where compare the `Telephones` and the id but for some reason I get duplicated entries.

```
Declare @ID int 
Set @ID = 1
UPDATE A
SET A.Telephone = 12345  FROM TelephoneOrg A, @TempOLDTelephones B , @TempNEWTelephones C
WHERE A.Telephone = B.Telephone and A.ID = @ID
```

Thanks in advance for any answer,

Dante.

Comment: Your data model appears to have issues with proper candidate keys being defined/present. This will make the work of your application (i.e., your update statement) more ambiguous, less effective and potentially disasterous. But, maybe you got that covered and just aren't showing it. For instance, you want to update the TelephonesOrganization table - but what is the key for that table? Without knowing that, it is difficult to answer the question.

Comment: You should have **explicit ID's** of some sort to link your two tables `TelephonesToUpdate` and `TelephonesNewValues` - **do not** rely on just an "ordering", since relational tables **do not** have any *implicit* ordering - you have to have something to use to link the two rows in the two separate tables!

Comment: The Primary key for TelephonesOrganization is the ID + the telephone as a Organization cant have 2 telephones, I Relay on Ordering because I know they will always be in that order. As the tables are the return of a function, but what do you refer by they don't have any implicit order?

Comment: In a relational database, the data **doesn't** have any implicit ordering - an order **only** occurs when you do a `SELECT` and explicitly add an `ORDER BY` clause. Relying on an "implicit" order is very fragile and not very reliable - I would never do something like that ...

Comment: I created the tables from a long string that represents a collection of values,  each value is separated with comas, in this case as the table has an order in which it inserts the values, for example the first value of the string would be the first row the second value goes on the second row and so on. How can the order change in this case?. I followed your advise for the moment anyway I don't want to mess the db. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have no id between TelephonesToUpdate and TelephonesNewValues but the order is the same, so we can create one with ROW_NUMBER: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.100).aspx

```
UPDATE t
  SET t.Telephone = b.Telephone
FROM TelephonesOrganization AS t
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS 'ID'
   ,Telephone
   FROM TelephonesToUpdate
) AS a
  ON t.Telephone = a.Telephone
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS 'ID'
   ,Telephone
   FROM TelephonesNewValues
) AS b
  ON a.ID = b.ID
;
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle you can play with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c15d/3

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with a code similar to that one, and its worked perfectly., And yes I have no keys that link the two tables I just thought of using the order to link them

Comment: Also thanks for the link I didn't know that a webpage like that one existed. it will come handy for little tests

Answer (score 0):

```
update TelephonesOrganization o
   set o.Telephone = ( select u.TelephonesNewValues
                         from TelephonesToUpdate u
                        where u.Telephone = o.Telephone )
 where o.ID = 1
   and exists ( select u.TelephonesNewValues
                  from TelephonesToUpdate u
                 where u.Telephone = o.Telephone );
```

UPDATE: I answered this before the question was updated. I did not think TelephoneNewValues was a table. I thought it was a column of the TelephoneToUpdate table. Also I had an error in my exists clause.